# Crash when pushing from UICollectionViewController to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently facing a problem with my app. 
I have a UICollectionViewController embed in a NavigationController embed in a TabBarController.

Basically, I have a collection of users, and when I click it, I want to go to the detail view.

When I try to perform the segue, a crash occurs, and I get the message: "********* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: **'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'**"

My storyboard structure looks like this :

**UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UICollectionViewController -> UiViewController**

```
@interface AnnuaireCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *photos;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *noms;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *users;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collection;

@end
```

My preparForSegue Method :

```
#pragma mark - Prepare for Segue
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

    UserDetailViewController *userDetailViewController = (UserDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    userDetailViewController.userImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    userDetailViewController.user = [self.users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

The StoryBoard:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/856Iq.png

I looked the sample codes on the apple docs, and everything seems similar, I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if written 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported', then don't push it. Replase, present modal, etc. There is plenty methods presenting viewcontrollers.

Comment: The problem is that Apple sample code used the push method (so I know it is possible), and I need it to go back the way I need.

Comment: @Kawada, I am pretty sure, that in this sample code pushed not `UINavigationController`

Comment: I downloaded the following code from apple docs website: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012860

Comment: @Kawada, there is pushed `DetailViewController` subclassed from `UIViewController`, not from `UINavigationController`, as I writed in first comment. I think yours `UserDetailViewController` is subclassed from `UINavigationController`.

Comment: That's exactly that, I feel shameful. Thanks a lot!